# How to encompass the first letter in every word with HTML tags?

Tags: php, replace

How to encompass the first letter in every word with HTML tags?

For example:

```
$string = replace_first_word("some simple text",'<big>{L}</big>');
echo $string; //returns: <big>s</big>ome <big>s</big>imple <big>t</big>ext
```

**edit**:
ohhh, forgot to mention one important point, it Needs to work with UTF-8 Unicode...
because I'm planning to support both Russian and English with this.

Comment: If you just want to display it differently: Did you try the `:first-letter` pseudo-element? (See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter)

Comment: thanks for the tip gumbo, but i need to replace the first letter of every word, not just the sentence.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Does it need to be server side, or would js do?

Comment: I need this to increase the size of each first letter of a already capitalized string.
I prefer server side as its more reliable, and as far as i know (and i don't know much) javascript is a pain when working with multibyte characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?:^|\b)(\p{L})(\p{L}*)/u', '<big>$1</big>$2', 'some simple words');
```

Or if you want it in a function:

```
function replace_first_word($str, $format) {
    return preg_replace('/(?:^|\b)(\p{L})(\p{L}*)/u', str_replace('{L}', '$1', $format).'$2', $str);
}
```

Comment: i would accept this as the accepted answer, but i really need it to work with unicode characters. :(

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: Oh, I forgot the *u* modifier. It should work now.

Comment: I can't get it to work, it still only select the first letter of every "latin" word.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: It seems that it needed some more tweaking. It should work now.

Comment: i accepted this as its the closest to what i asked, even though it does not work... 
mine works but putting my own answer as the best answer sounds wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Standard warning: manipulating HTML with regexes is a bad idea because it's next to impossible to correctly handle nesting, content inside tags vs outside, etc. So if you need a complete solution, parse the HTML and then manipulate text nodes.

In this psecific example that you've given, this should do it.

```
$output = preg_replace('!\b([a-zA-Z])!`, '<big>$1</big>`, $input);
```

It means find a word boundary (`\b`), which is zero width, and wrap the following letter in a `<big>` element.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the CSS property

```
p { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

From [Sitepoint's CSS reference on text-transform](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-transform):

> capitalize
>
> - transforms the first character in each word to uppercase; all other characters remain unaffected — they’re not transformed to lowercase, but will appear as written in the document

Comment: thanks gordon, i actually know the guy who wrote the reference :)
its the best one yet.

but i don't need to capitalize every letter of a already capitalized sentence text-transform: uppercase; ;)

Comment: @YuriKolovsky would `p {
   text-transform: capitalize;
   font-variant: Small-caps;
}` be a solution?

Comment: I'm doing some q/a maintenance: yes, it would be a solution that works in all browsers except IE5. It would be the most elegant solution here, if I didn't mention HTML it would be the Best answer. I don't know why you didn't get up-voted more.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is

```
preg_replace('~(?<=\p{^L}|^)\p{L}~u', '<big>$0</big>', $input);
```

note that \b does not work properly with utf8.

Comment: note that \b does not work properly with utf8: yes i noticed :(

Comment: It works for latin characters, but not with UTF-8
for example: "test text" works fine
while: "тест техт" outputs: Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚ Ñ‚ÐµÑ…Ñ‚

Answer (score 0):

here is a better and possibly faster version that i just found out myself, that supports utf-8 multibyte characters.

in my experience regex functions are slow in php, so here is a string manipulation based function.

```
function replace_first_word($text,$format='<big>{L}</big>'){
 //*** UTF-8 replace first letter of every word ***
 //split words
 $words = explode(' ', $text);
 //pick up each word
 foreach($words as &$word){
  //find out first letter of word
  $first = substr($word, 0,1);
  //remove first letter from word
  $word = substr($word,1);
  //replace first letter with formatted letter
  $first = str_replace('{L}',$first,$format);
  //add replaced letter to word
  $word = $first.$word;
 }
 //glue words back together and return them
    return implode(' ',$words);
}
```

also before php6 comes out, remember to set these 2 variables in php.ini to better support utf-8

```
mbstring.func_overload "7"
mbstring.internal_encoding "UTF-8"
```

Comment: If you expect a multibyte string then you should use multibyte functions.

Comment: oh, your right.
just set these in php.ini
mbstring.func_overload "7"
mbstring.internal_encoding "UTF-8"